# Visibility style binding using knockout.js fails

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, knockout.js, visibility

```
data-bind="style : { display : repeat() === 'Custom' ? 'block' : 'none' }"
```

This style binding succeeds using knockout where as the following fails

```
data-bind="style : { visibility : repeat() === 'Custom' ? 'visible' : 'hidden' }"
```

Why?

I can use visible binding but in my case I don't want to lose that div space even when it is hidden.

How can I achieve this?

I don't want to make this happen using jquery as I have already succeeded using it.

Comment: Using the visiblity with the style binding should work just fine. See also in this example: http://jsfiddle.net/SUaB4/. So please create a jsfiddle which demonstrates your issue!

Comment: @nemesv beat me to it but I'll post my fiddle anyhow showing it works: http://jsfiddle.net/9bgM2/ must be something else in play in your css or knockout that is causing it to fail

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Another option to solve this issue is to create your own binding.  That sounds hard, but it's really easy and KO was designed with custom binding in mind.  I wish the base package had more of them, but they are trivial to create. The advantage to this solution is that your binding is simple and more legible. Here is an example, called hidden:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.hidden = (function() {
    function setVisibility(element, valueAccessor) {
        var hidden = ko.unwrap(valueAccessor());
        $(element).css('visibility', hidden ? 'hidden' : 'visible');
    }
    return { init: setVisibility, update: setVisibility };
})();
```

And used in your HTML as:

```
data-bind="hidden: !repeat()"
```

Answer (score 9):

I just did something very similar and this worked for me:

```
data-bind="style : { visibility : repeat() === 'Custom' ? '' : 'hidden' }"
```

The difference is setting `visibility` to `''` rather than `visible`.

Answer (score 2):

Would probably be better to use the `css` binding http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/css-binding.html.  You could also tidy the whole thing with a `computed` observable.

```
self.hidden = ko.computed(function() {
    return self.repeat() !== 'Custom';
})
```

Your binding is now this simple `data-bind="css: { hide: hidden }"`

In your CSS provide the following class:

```
.hide {
    visibility: 'hidden';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me, to make a div be visible only after the page has loaded, using `visibility`:

```
<div style="visibility:hidden" data-bind="style: {visibility: 'visible'}">
    ...
</div>
```